# REGEX for any file extension

Tags: regex

I am trying to build a regex to tell if a string is a valid file extension. It could be any extentions.

```
hello        no
.hello       Yes
..hello      No
hello.world  No
.hello.world No
.hello world No
```

I have tried ^\. and ^\.[\.] but can't get what i am looking for. This seems like it should be simple.

Comment: I started to do that too, like everyone else but [^.] fails on their last example... (.hello world).

Comment: Before you can write a regular expression, you have to be able to describe, in English, the rules that you're trying to implement.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
^\.[^.]+$
```

This means start with `.` and then anything other than dot (`.`)

You can also use this one if you want to have only aplhanumeric.:

```
^\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

Comment: Thanks! Figured it was something easy like this

Comment: If the file extension is at the end of a string for example `/example/image.svg` this will work too `\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`

Comment: What about extensions like `.tar.gz`?

Answer (score 5):

Try this regex:

```
^\.[\w]+$
```

Matches a string starting with a ".", followed by one or more "word" character(s), until the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex, which matches all strings starting with a dot followed by at least one other character:

```
^\.[^.]+$
```

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a string like `".hello"` with the extension and you're just testing it to see if it matches then you can try something like `^\.[^\\/:*?"<>|\s.]{1,255}$`. It works with all of your example cases.

The beginning `^\.` means the whole string must start with a literal dot "."

The `[^\\/:*?"<>|\s.]` means that after the dot you can have any character except a backslash, forward slash, colon, asterisk, question mark, double quotation mark, less than or greater than symbol, vertical bar, whitespace character, or dot. Feel free to add whatever other characters you'd like to disallow inside of the square brackets after the carrot or delete any characters that I added that you wish to allow.
(Note: the allowable characters for [filenames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename)/[extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename_extension) depends on the file system.)

The `{1,255}$` at the end quantifies the amount of allowable characters that we just defined all the way until the end of the string. So anything that's after the dot and allowed can be between 1 and 255 characters long and it must go on until the end of the string. Feel free to change the 255 to any number that you like. 
(Note: the maximum length for filenames/extensions depends on the file system.)

If you are searching a string like `"https://sub.example.com/directory1/directory2/file.php"` for the file extension you should instead use `\.[^\\/:*?"<>|\s.]{1,255}$` to search for the final extension including the dot.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in javascript

```
^[.][a-zA-Z0-9.,$;]+$
```

Comment: Althought the OP isn't clear about, what ```any``` means, this solution discards some valid letters/signs for file extensions, like ```-``` and ```+```. Have you tried the accepted answer in javascript? It would be interesting to see if it does work there, too?

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
(?:.*\\)+([^\\]+)
```

for Windows for it produces short filename with extension.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a regex to get the file extension from a filename, here it is

```
(?<=\.)[^.\s]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

`^\.\w+$` should work
`^` - begin of line starts with `\.` - dot, then `\w` (equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_]) until the and of string `$`

Comment: This duplicates [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22235655/735926) and --if you exclude the underscore-- the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22235556/735926).

Comment: Hi @bfontaine, That answer contains list tokens `[ ]` which are useless here. And my answer is shorter

Comment: You should suggest an edit to the other answer instead of adding a new one.