# Regex that excludes filename with certains extensions

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to find a regex that allows filename which do not have certains extensions. For example:

- test.pdf => ok
- test.exe => ko
- test.tmp => ko
- test.EXE => ko
- test.PDF => ok

I can't use ends with because I have to put the entire RegEx in a .properties file.

I tried `^.*\.(^exe|^tmp)$` but it does not work at all.

EDIT: this is not a duplicate of [REGEX for any file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22235518/regex-for-any-file-extension) because I need to ignore certain extensions. That is not the purpose of the other question.

Comment: Please [check this](https://regex101.com/r/6FMPm6/3).

Comment: `/.+\.(?!exe|tmp)/i`

Comment: How about `!s.matches("(?i).*\\.(exe|tmp)")`?

Comment: @revo you're right, what I said is [correct in some languages](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#limitbehind) but not in Java nor generally in PCRE (relevant part of the linked resource : "While Perl requires alternatives inside lookbehind to have the same length, PCRE allows alternatives of variable length.")

Comment: Yes, the term is *variable-length alternatives* (*width* in unlikely to be used except in rare cases). Java has no problem in dealing with it. Perl doesn't support it nor does Python itself but its [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/)'s shipped with this feature. @Aaron

Answer (score 1):

hope this might help!

```
public class StackOverflowQuestion45321328 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> data = new ArrayList();
        data.add("test.pdf");
        data.add("test.exe");
        data.add("test.tmp");
        data.add("test.EXE");
        data.add("test.PDF");

        String regex = "^.*(?<!exe|tmp)$";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

        for (String filename : data) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(filename);
            boolean isMatchingPattern = matcher.matches();
            System.out.println(filename + " : " + isMatchingPattern);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
test.pdf : true
test.exe : false
test.tmp : false
test.EXE : false
test.PDF : true
```

Comment: Note that this rejects filenames ending in `exe` or `tmp` whether they are the full extension or not, i.e.`noextensionexe` or `biggerextension.hexe`

Comment: Altering the regex to "^.*(?<!\\.exe|\\.tmp)$" shouldn't reject noextensionexe and biggerextension.hexe

Answer (score 0):

Let try this regex:

```
.*\.(?!(exe|tmp|EXE|TMP))(.+)

test.pdf -> OK
test.exe 
test.tmp 
test.EXE 
test.PDF 
tets.abcd.dfdf -> OK
abc.exe
abc.tmp
aexe.abc -> OK
```

Hop this help!

Comment: This will match filenames it shouldn't when there are multiple dots in the filename, for example `myApp.1.2.3.exe`

Comment: @Aaron OK, I got it.